# How can I loop correctly a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

[image]

```
for user in df_enlaces['CorreoElectronico'].values:

  to_mail=(df_enlaces.set_index('CorreoElectronico').loc[user].index[0])

  print(to_mail, df_enlaces.set_index('CorreoElectronico').loc[user]['Enlace'])
```

The output of the above code is:

```
example1@mail.com CorreoElectronico
example1@mail.com    link1
example1@mail.com    link2
Name: Enlace, dtype: object
example1@mail.com CorreoElectronico
example1@mail.com    link1
example1@mail.com    link2
Name: Enlace, dtype: object
example2@mail.com CorreoElectronico
example2@mail.com    link3
example2@mail.com    link4
example2@mail.com    link5
Name: Enlace, dtype: object
example2@mail.com CorreoElectronico
example2@mail.com    link3
example2@mail.com    link4
example2@mail.com    link5
Name: Enlace, dtype: object
example2@mail.com CorreoElectronico
example2@mail.com    link3
example2@mail.com    link4
example2@mail.com    link5
Name: Enlace, dtype: object
```

However, it is repeated. Something I am doing wrong when looping. I just want to match the user email with its link in the column ['Enlace'].
The desired output would be:

```
example1@mail.com    link1
example1@mail.com    link2
example2@mail.com    link3
example2@mail.com    link4
example2@mail.com    link5
```

Comment: Generally, with Pandas, you don't manually loop. Read through the user's guide to get some idea how to work with Pandas.

Comment: Your input dataframe is unreadable: please don't provide data as images, but use copy-paste code (i.e., the creation of a sample dataframe).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like this should do the trick:

```
users = ['user1', 'user1', 'user2', 'user2', 'user3']
links = ['link1', 'link2', 'link3', 'link4', 'link5']
df = pd.DataFrame({'user':users,'link':links})

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    print(row['user'], row['link'])
```

At least it does when you just want to print the user and link from each row in the dataframe?
This outputs:

```
user1 link1
user1 link2
user2 link3
user2 link4
user3 link5
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
for user in df_enlaces['CorreoElectronico'].unique():
    ....
```

You are looping through each value in the `CorreoElectronico` column and then when you perform `.loc` it pulls out every row which matches that user (and there are several)

Answer (score 1):

As I suppose, you want to:

- iterate over rows of *df_enlaces*,
- from each row print the e-mail address (*CorreoElectronico*) and the
  link (*Enlace*).

To do it, use the following loop:

```
for _, row in df_enlaces.iterrows():
    print(f'{row.CorreoElectronico}    {row.Enlace}')
```